# How to check driver code signing policy is enabled and actually work?

Tags: c#, c++, security, certificate, driver

> Starting with 64-bit versions of Windows Vista and later versions of Windows, driver code signing policy requires that all driver code have a digital signature. In addition, certain configurations of 32-bit versions of Windows Vista and later versions of Windows also require driver code to be digitally-signed in order to access next generation premium content that is controlled by the content protection policy.

And in any time you can disable this check with (from [How to Test-Sign a Driver Package](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff553484(v=vs.85).aspx)):

```
Bcdedit.exe -set TESTSIGNING OFF
```

And reboot after it. After it you can install any driver you want to user pc. Our software use driver to protect it memory from read/write. But if you can install driver with hand made certificate you can break protection and do that you want. To prevent this behaviour i want to check environment about actual status of code signing policy.

### Questions:

1. How to check is code signing policy enabled and work using c++/c#?
2. Is there some api to chech already loaded driver certificate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer to the first question:

Such things in Windows is managed by registry keys. The registry key responsible for boot configuration data is stored under "HKLM\BCD00000000". It includes different objects each of them including different elements.

In your case "{9dea862c-5cdd-4e70-acc1-f32b344d4795}" object contains an element named "23000003". By checking the "Element" value of "23000003" you reach to another GUID. You can find that particular GUID under the "HKLM\BCD00000000\Objects".

If we call that key GUIDXXX, you can find the dword value controlling the TESTSIGNING under "HKLM\BCD00000000\GUIDXXX\Elements\16000049" : Element. By setting this value to 0 you disable the TESTSIGING and by setting to 1 you enable TESTSIGING mode.
Also you can just check the value to recognize whether it's on or off.

About APIs you can use registry APIs such as RegOpen, RegQuery*, RegSet*, etc.

I put these links as reference. It contains lots of helpful info and details about the key.

http://www.mistyprojects.co.uk/documents/BCDEdit/files/bcd_as_registry_hive.htm

http://www.mistyprojects.co.uk/documents/BCDEdit/files/object_element_codes.htm#generic